# Results equivalent to Gauss's Eureka Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The fact that every integer of the form $8n+3$ can be expressed as the sum of three squares can easily be shown to be equivalent to Gauss's Theorem that every positive integer is the sum of three or fewer triangular numbers.

Is Legendre's result that every odd integer is the sum of four squares of which two are equal also equivalent to Gauss's Theorem?

Comment: We know that they are both true, so they are equivalent. Usually when stating that something is equivalent to something else, it is only meaningful when the truth of both are unknown. What you are asking is probably a simple implication in both directions. But then "simple" is not a logically rigorous term, just as e.g. "elementary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the book this table comes from

[image]

..........................

Comment: Thanks. I believe I've now spotted the connection  with other results that I required - see other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a full answer but is the connection I required and which I've now seen.

If $N$ is an odd integer, then $2N$ is the sum of three squares precisely one of which must be even. Let $2N=U^2+V^2+4W^2$, then $N=(\frac{U+V}{2})^2+(\frac{U-V}{2})^2+2W^2$.

Comment: in that case, take a look at   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jagy_Encyclopedia.pdf